# Let $f:[a,b] \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ and $g:[a,b] \mapsto [c,d]$ is a differentiable function then prove that $\varphi$ is differentiable.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

> Let $f : [a, b] \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ be continuous and $g : [c, d] \mapsto [a, b]$ be differentiable. Define $\varphi(x) := \int_{a}^{g(x)}f(t) dt$. Prove that $\varphi$ is differentiable and compute its derivative.

My attempt:The only thing that I could understand is $|\varphi(x+h) - \varphi(x)| = |\int_{a}^{g(x+h)}f(t)dt - \int_{a}^{g(x)}f(t)dt| = |\int_{g(x)}^{g(x+h)}f(t)dt| \le \int_{g(x)}^{g(x+h)}|f(t)|dt$

Since $f(x)$ is continuous and so it is integrable. Let $P$ be a partition on $[g(x),g(x+h)]$ then $\{g(x) = x_0 ,x_1 , \cdots , g(x+h)=x_n\}$ be a partition on the given interval.

We know that $f(x)$ is continuous so it is bounded in the interval $[g(x),g(x+h)]$.Also $|f(x)|$ is bounded and integrable.

We can conclude that $\int_{g(x)}^{g(x+h)}|f(t)|dt = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\mbox{sup}f(x)_{x \in [g(x),g(x+h)]}(x_{i+1} - x_i) \le M(g(x+h) - g(x)) < M \frac{\epsilon}{M} < \epsilon$ ( we can choose such an $h>0$ such that the above holds )

This is what my attempt has been to show that $\varphi$ is continuous. I cannot conclude the differentiability part.

Some hints instead of a complete answer will be helpful.

Comment: Don't we have $\varphi(x) = F(g(x))$ where $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$ ?

Comment: Set $F$ to be the antiderivative of $f$ that vanishes at $a$, and re-write the integral in terms of $F$. What is the regularity of $F$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\varphi(x+h) - \varphi(x)}{h} 
&= \lim_{h\to0}\frac{1}{h}\int_{g(x)}^{g(x+h)} f(t) \\[1mm]
&= \lim_{h\to0}\frac{F(g(x+h)) - F(g(x))}{h} \\[1mm]
&= \left(F(g(x))\right)' \\[1mm]
&= F'(g(x))g'(x) \\[1mm]
&= f(g(x))g'(x)\end{align}$$
hence $\varphi(x)$ is differentiable and its derivative is $f(g(x))g'(x)$.